# Give option to user for Notifications from the app

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, settings, localnotification

I have implemented Local Notification in my app. The app will remind the user every day about something. I want to give user the option to switch off local notification from settings. How can that be done?

Comment: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/05/18/adding-a-settings-bundle-to-an-iphone-app.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when user turn-off loca notification execute below mentioned code.

```
 UIApplication *app=[UIApplication sharedApplication];
 [app scheduleLocalNotification:nil];
```